# Get UTF-16 code unit at a given index in ABAP

Tags: encoding, abap, utf-16

I want to get the UTF-16 code unit at a given index in ABAP.

Same can be done in JavaScript with `charCodeAt()`.

For example `"d".charCodeAt();` will give back 100.

Is there a similar functionality in ABAP?

Comment: When you say the "UTF-16 code unit", either you mean the Unicode code point, e.g. "d" is always `U+0064` (official "name" of Unicode character, 0x0064 being the hex representation of 100), while UTF-16 little endian (SAP code page 4103) and big endian (SAP code page 4102) encode "d" differently, respectively 2 bytes 0x4400 and 2 bytes 0x0044.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with class CL_ABAP_CONV_OUT_CE

```
DATA(lo_converter) = cl_abap_conv_out_ce=>create( encoding = '4103' ). "Litte Endian

TRY.
    CALL METHOD lo_converter->convert
      EXPORTING
        data   = 'a'
        n      = 1
      IMPORTING
        buffer = DATA(lv_buffer). "lv_buffer will 0061
CATCH ...

ENDTRY.
```

Codepage 4102 is for UTF-16 Big endian.

It is possible to encode not just a single character, but a string as well:

```
      EXPORTING
        data   = 'abc'
        n      = 3
```

"n" always stands for the length of the string you want to be encoded. It could be less, than the actual length of the string.

Comment: I think `4103` is little endian and `4102` is big endian.

Comment: You are right, like always, I edited my answer.

Comment: Note that `n` is optional and the method deduces it automatically from the length of `data`.

Answer (score 3):

When you say you "want to get the UTF-16 code unit",

- either you mean the Unicode code point, e.g. the character `d` is always [`U+0064`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0064/index.htm) (official "name" of Unicode character, the two bytes `0x0064` being the hexadecimal representation of decimal `100`),
- or you mean you want to encode `d` to UTF-16 little endian (SAP code page 4103) or big endian (SAP code page 4102) which gives respectively 2 bytes `0x4400` or 2 bytes `0x0044`.

For the second case, see József answer.

For the first case, you may get it using the method `UCCP` (UniCode Code Point) or `UCCPI` (UniCode Code Point Integer) of class `CL_ABAP_CONV_OUT_CE`:

```
DATA: l_unicode_point_hex TYPE x LENGTH 2,
      l_unicode_point_int TYPE i.


l_unicode_point_hex = cl_abap_conv_out_ce=>UCCP( 'd' ).

ASSERT l_unicode_point_hex = '0064'.


l_unicode_point_int = cl_abap_conv_out_ce=>UCCPI( 'd' ).

ASSERT l_unicode_point_int = 100.
```

EDIT: Note that the two methods return always the same values whatever the SAP system code page is (`4102`, `4103` or whatever).